# term_start won't open terminal in the desired position

Tags: vimscript, terminal, macvim

If I run `term_start('zsh', {'term_name': 'MYTER','vertical': v:true})` I get the expected behavior, but if I run `term_start('zsh', {'term_name': 'MYTER','belowright': v:true})` will produce `E475: Invalid argument: belowright`, in-spite from the [doc](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_start%28%29) one can read

> "vertical"        split the window vertically; note that
> other window position can be defined with
> command modifiers, such as :belowright.

I am using MacVim 9.0.

Comment: Could we ask you if you are you using Vim or Neovim?

Comment: I am using MacVim. Edited main post.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt No `term_start()` in Neovim.

Comment: you probably need to understand what they mean by command modifier. I have no clue.

Comment: Checked. belowright appears to be a command modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vertical` mentioned in the doc is a key in a dictionary. The function knows how to handle that `vertical` key but it can't handle *any* arbitrary key like `belowright` or `foobar`. In other words, `belowright` is not part of the type expected by the function so you get an error if you try it.

The command modifiers in question are `:help :vertical`, `:help :belowright`, `:help :topleft`, etc. They are used before a command that creates a new window, to influence how the split is done.

In this case, "the command that creates a new window" is the whole:

```
:call term_start('zsh', {'term_name': 'MYTER', 'vertical': v:true})
```

which means that you are supposed to use `:belowright` like this:

```
:belowright call term_start('zsh', {'term_name': 'MYTER', 'vertical': v:true})
```

Comment: In-fact I had the feeling that `vertical` was a pre-defined key of a dictionary and that my attempt was not going to work. I also try the nastier `...'vertical': belowright` :D Needless to say it didn't work - it, not surprisingly, complained about the value type associated to the key `vertical` :D  
Nevertheless, I solved with `botright term_start(...` in my vimscript. :)

Comment: Why not removing vertical key if you can use the keyword vertical as command modifier like belowright, etc? That would be a more neat implementation imo.